# Android - Two Vertical RecyclerView inside Vertical Scroll view, I need to perform load more for each recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need two vertical `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView`. I need to add a  **load more** footer for each list in the `RecyclerView`. How this can be achieved in android?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for. [Showing multiple lists in a single `RecyclerView`](https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview). I'm putting the description from [wiki](https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview/wiki) to describe how this can be achieved easily.

This is a simple mockup to make it clear about what we're trying to achieve.

**List Header (First List)**

- Item 1 of first list
- Item 2 of first list
- Item 3 of first list

**List Header (Second List)**

- Item 1 of second list
- Item 2 of second list
- Item 3 of second list
- Item 4 of second list

**Footer View**

Let us take two lists named `firstList` and `secondList`. Both are a list of some objects. 
You need to declare them globally and initialize them globally. So that you don't have to pass any specific list to your `Adapter`.

**Defining your views**

So before initializing your `Adapter` you need to declare some constants so that you can differentiate different types of views you're going to populate in your list. For example, in my case, I have five different views and I've assigned an unique value to each of these items so that I can explicitly tell which view to be shown when `getItemViewType` is called on `Adapter`.

```
private static final int FOOTER_VIEW = 1;
private static final int FIRST_LIST_ITEM_VIEW = 2;
private static final int FIRST_LIST_HEADER_VIEW = 3;
private static final int SECOND_LIST_ITEM_VIEW = 4;
private static final int SECOND_LIST_HEADER_VIEW = 5;
```

**Define `ViewHolder` class and bind each item properly**

Now lets customize your `ViewHolder`. We'll have the instances of the items which will be shown in each list item from here. We're maintaining two different lists here and let us assume each of these lists has a title and a description as the list item.

So we need to get the instances of those and should bind them with appropriate values. I'm adding an example from my code and you'll see two different function here, `bindViewFirstList()` and `bindViewSecondList` to bind the UI fields with appropriate values. There's another function which is `bindViewFooter()` to customize the footer view of our second list. You might declare some other functions like `bindViewHeaderFirstList()` and `bindViewHeaderSecondList` to customize and set values of your headers from here. Here's my code sample of `ViewHolder`.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // List items of first list
    private TextView mTextDescription1;
    private TextView mListItemTitle1;

    // List items of second list
    private TextView mTextDescription2;
    private TextView mListItemTitle2;

    // Element of footer view
    private TextView footerTextView;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Get the view of the elements of first list
        mTextDescription1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description1);
        mListItemTitle1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title1);

        // Get the view of the elements of second list
        mTextDescription2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description2);
        mListItemTitle2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title2);

        // Get the view of the footer elements
        footerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer);
    }

    public void bindViewSecondList(int pos) {

        // Have a close look here. We're calculating the appropriate position of the item in the secondList
        // Second list will be populated after the firstList
        // So if the firstList doesn't have any item the secondList will have a header and its items.
        if (firstList == null) pos = pos - 1;
        else {
            // If the firstList is not empty, it'll have its header and its items. See the else part.
            if (firstList.size() == 0) pos = pos - 1;
            else pos = pos - firstList.size() - 2;
        }

        final String description = secondList.get(pos).getDescription();
        final String title = secondList.get(pos).getTitle();

        mTextDescription2.setText(description);
        mListItemTitle2.setText(title);
    }

    public void bindViewFirstList(int pos) {

        // Have a close look here. We're calculating the appropriate position of the item in the firstList
        // Decrease pos by 1 as there is a header view now.
        pos = pos - 1;

        final String description = firstList.get(pos).getDescription();
        final String title = firstList.get(pos).getTitle();

        mTextDescription1.setText(description);
        mListItemTitle1.setText(title);
    }

    public void bindViewFooter(int pos) {
        footerTextView.setText("This is footer");
    }
}
```

**Get your custom `ViewHolder` for each type of view**

Now declare custom `ViewHolder` for each of your element so that you can differentiate them when `onBindViewHolder` gets called on `Adapter`.

```
public class FooterViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class FirstListHeaderViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public FirstListHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class FirstListItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public FirstListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class SecondListHeaderViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public SecondListHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class SecondListItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public SecondListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

**Get proper layout files for each type of list items**

In your `onCreateViewHolder` you need to `return` the layout associated with the specific list item. Here's mine.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v;

    if (viewType == FOOTER_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_footer, parent, false);
        FooterViewHolder vh = new FooterViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    } else if (viewType == FIRST_LIST_ITEM_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_first_list, parent, false);
        FirstListItemViewHolder vh = new FirstListItemViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    } else if (viewType == FIRST_LIST_HEADER_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_first_list_header, parent, false);
        FirstListHeaderViewHolder vh = new FirstListHeaderViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    } else if (viewType == SECOND_LIST_HEADER_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_second_list_header, parent, false);
        SecondListHeaderViewHolder vh = new SecondListHeaderViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    } else {
        // SECOND_LIST_ITEM_VIEW
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_second_list, parent, false);
        SecondListItemViewHolder vh = new SecondListItemViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
}
```

**Populate each type of views with proper elements from `onBindViewHolder`**

Check if the `ViewHolder` passed to `onBindViewHolder` is an instance of an item you want to show in that specific **`position`**.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        if (holder instanceof SecondListItemViewHolder) {
            SecondListItemViewHolder vh = (SecondListItemViewHolder) holder;
            vh.bindViewSecondList(position);

        } else if (holder instanceof FirstListHeaderViewHolder) {
            FirstListHeaderViewHolder vh = (FirstListHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        } else if (holder instanceof FirstListItemViewHolder) {
            FirstListItemViewHolder vh = (FirstListItemViewHolder) holder;
            vh.bindViewFirstList(position);

        } else if (holder instanceof SecondListHeaderViewHolder) {
            SecondListHeaderViewHolder vh = (SecondListHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        } else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            FooterViewHolder vh = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            vh.bindViewFooter(position);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Get the item count of the `RecyclerView`**

Here's a tricky part of this `Adapter`. You might have three cases here. Either your first list can be empty or the second one. The third case is, both lists are populated with some data.

So, we need to consider each of these three cases here. In my example, I've a header in my first list. In case of my second list I want to show a header along with a footer. So my `getItemCount` looks like this.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    int firstListSize = 0;
    int secondListSize = 0;

    if (secondList == null && firstList == null) return 0;

    // Get the sizes of the lists 
    if (secondList != null)
        secondListSize = secondList.size();
    if (firstList != null)
        firstListSize = firstList.size();

    // Case 1: When both lists have data
    if (secondListSize > 0 && firstListSize > 0)
        return 1 + firstListSize + 1 + secondListSize + 1;   // first list header, first list size, second list header , second list size, footer
    // Case 2: When only the second list have data
    else if (secondListSize > 0 && firstListSize == 0)
        return 1 + secondListSize + 1;                       // second list header, second list size, footer
    // Case 3: When only the first list have data
    else if (secondListSize == 0 && firstListSize > 0)
        return 1 + firstListSize;                            // first list header , first list size
    else return 0;
}
```

**Return proper item view from `getItemViewType`**

Here's the trickiest part of this `Adapter` I guess. You need to calculate which item view to be returned when a specific `position` of the item in your list is given.

The simplest way to get this thing done is to write the logic of returning the views of headers and footer first. When you're done with writing the logic of defining the `position` of your headers and footers, its easy to write for the others.

Here's how I've managed mine. See, I've defined the position for the headers and footers first which have simplified the other equations for me.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int firstListSize = 0;
    int secondListSize = 0;

    if (secondList == null && firstList == null)
        return super.getItemViewType(position);

    if (secondList != null)
        secondListSize = secondList.size();
    if (firstList != null)
        firstListSize = firstList.size();

    if (secondListSize > 0 && firstListSize > 0) {
        if (position == 0) return FIRST_LIST_HEADER_VIEW;
        else if (position == firstListSize + 1)
            return SECOND_LIST_HEADER_VIEW;
        else if (position == secondListSize + 1 + firstListSize + 1)
            return FOOTER_VIEW;
        else if (position > firstListSize + 1)
            return SECOND_LIST_ITEM_VIEW;
        else return FIRST_LIST_ITEM_VIEW;

    } else if (secondListSize > 0 && firstListSize == 0) {
        if (position == 0) return SECOND_LIST_HEADER_VIEW;
        else if (position == secondListSize + 1) return FOOTER_VIEW;
        else return SECOND_LIST_ITEM_VIEW;

    } else if (secondListSize == 0 && firstListSize > 0) {
        if (position == 0) return FIRST_LIST_HEADER_VIEW;
        else return FIRST_LIST_ITEM_VIEW;
    }

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

You're done with the implementation of your custom `Adapter` when multiple lists are needed to be shown in a single `RecyclerView`. I've added a demo project in the [code](https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview) section. You can build and run the project.

Cheers!

Comment: How to implement load-more for each recyclerview. if am scrolling both the views are scrolled. how to manage first recyclerview load-more and second recyclerview load-more. ?

Comment: If you're using my project, then you already have a footer after your second list. You need a footer after your first list too? Just add another `VIEW_TYPE` and modify the `getItemCount()` and `getItemViewType()` functions accordingly. Please read the wiki again to get clearer idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter), you can build something like the image below:

[image]

You can find the full code of that screen [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example2Fragment.java).

Then when the user clicks on "See more" (or "Load more" in you case), you just load more items, add them to the respective Section and notify the adapter. Something like:

```
worldSection.addItem("Another world news item here");
sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```